# How to not display duplicate values from database table to client form in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table **video_tbl** as follows

```
id       vdate             vname 
1        2016-01-05        dssfsd    
2        2016-02-11        vxc  
3        2016-02-16        vgjhgh      
4        2015-06-12        xcbcvxb       
5        2014-12-03        gjm vcb
```

I want to show ***vdate*** years only in drop down list like

```
2016
2015
2014
```

But my output was like this

```
2016
2016
2016
2016
2015
2014
```

in dropdown list.

```
<?php
$sql_videodate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cf_crane_video ORDER BY cf_vdate",$con);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($sql_videodate))
$vdate = $row1->cf_vdate;
$orderdate = explode('-', $vdate);$month = $orderdate[1];$day   = $orderdate[2];$year  = $orderdate[0];
?>
```

Comment: Iam using code is <select class="form-control" id="videodate" name="videodate">
       <?php 
       $sql_videodate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cf_crane_video ORDER BY cf_vdate",$con);
      while($row1 = mysql_fetch_object($sql_videodate)){
$vdate = $row1->cf_vdate;
$orderdate = explode('-', $vdate);
$month = $orderdate[1];
$day   = $orderdate[2];
$year  = $orderdate[0];
?>
        <option value="<?php echo $year;?>"><?php echo $year;?></option>
        <?php }?>
      </select>

Comment: use        SELECT distinct YEAR(vdate) FROM cf_crane_video ORDER BY cf_vdate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;)

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c532c/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE video_tbl 
    (`id` int, `vdate` datetime, `vname` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO video_tbl 
    (`id`, `vdate`, `vname`)
VALUES
    (1, '2016-01-05 00:00:00', 'dssfsd'),
    (2, '2016-02-11 00:00:00', 'vxc'),
    (3, '2016-02-16 00:00:00', 'vgjhgh'),
    (4, '2015-06-12 00:00:00', 'xcbcvxb'),
    (5, '2014-12-03 00:00:00', 'gjm vcb')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(`vdate`) year FROM video_tbl ORDER BY `vdate` DESC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c532c/2/0)**:

```
| year |
|------|
| 2016 |
| 2015 |
| 2014 |
```

Answer (score 0):

try to group in your SQL

```
GROUP BY YEAR(vdate)
```

Comment: Grouping without a aggregate function will be wrong when huge data is considered

Answer (score 0):

The ***SELECT DISTINCT*** statement is used to return only distinct (**different**) values

Usage:

> SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name FROM table_name;

This should return no duplicate values